# How can I plot a straight line which is in normal form?

Tags: geometry

Take a look at [this link](http://aishack.in/tutorials/hough-transform-normal/).

Suppose, I have the following equation of a straight line:

$$x  \cos\theta+ y \sin \theta=p$$

If we rearrange the equation as follows:

$$y = \frac{p - x\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

we are again stuck with infinite values of $x$. So, what is the benefit of introducing $\theta$ and $p$ here?

**How can/should I plot this?**

Comment: You should know that not every line can be written in the form $y=ax+b$ for some $a$ and $b$. Those are precisely the lines that are orthogonal to $x$ axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal form can be intepreted as follow, let

- $p$ the distance between the line and the origin
- $n=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ the normal unitary vector to the line

therefore for any point $OP=(x,y)$ on the line by dot product we have

$$OP\cdot n=(x,y)\cdot (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)=x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta=p$$

Note that for a given line $\theta$ and $p$  are fixed therefore by the following

$$y = \frac{p - x\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

for $\sin \theta \neq 0$ we can find all the points on the line.

Comment: but, the article says that $\theta=-90$ to $90$. so, zero is included here.

Comment: @yahoo.com for $\theta=0$ we can't divide and indeed form the normal form we obtain simply $x=p$ that is a line parallel to $y$ axis.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

All you need to plot the line is to obtain two points on this  line.

- If $\sin\theta,\:\cos\theta \ne 0$, the $x$- and $y$-intercepts $A$ and $B$ are given by
  $$x_A=\frac p{\cos\theta},\qquad y_B=\frac p{\sin\theta}.$$
  *Note*: this equation is close tto the standard form of the equation of a straight line, given its $x$- and $y$-intercepts $a$ and $b$:
  $$\frac xa+\frac yb=1.$$
- If $\cos\theta=0$, then $\sin\theta=1\:$ or $-1$, and the equation of the line is
  $$y=p\quad\text{ or }\quad y=-p. $$
- If $\sin\theta=0$, then $\cos\theta=1\:$  and the equation of the line is $\;x=p$.

Answer (score 0):

A line’s normal is perpendicular to the line: if it makes an angle of $\theta$ with the $x$-axis, then the line itself makes an angle of $\theta+\pi/2$ with the $x$-axis. Now, $\cos(\theta+\pi/2)=\sin\theta$ and $\sin(\theta+\pi/2)=-\cos\theta$, so if your equation of the line has the form $ax+by+c=0$, then a direction vector of the line is $(b,-a)$. This, together with a known point on the line, which you can find by plugging in a convenient value for $x$ or $y$ and solving for the other variable, should be enough information for you to plot the line.